# How to replace a stop function to loop

Tags: flash

Im using a supplied Flash template from the client that had a replay button but they wish for the ad banner to simply loop now, my problem is how do I do this with the below existing Action Script as the stop function is used to stop on frame 2 and carryout the fadein/out tweens...

```
stop();

import com.greensock.TweenNano;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

init();

function init():Void
{

    TweenNano.to(imgBG,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:0,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt1,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:1,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt2,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:2,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(txt2,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:5,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt3,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:6,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(txt3,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:9,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt4,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:10,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(txt4,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:15,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(hpLogoBlue,0,{_alpha:100,delay:0,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(ctaBtn,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:11,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(ctaBtn,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:15,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

}

ctaBtn.onRollOver = function():Void 
{
    ctaBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
};
ctaBtn.onRollOut = function():Void 
{
    ctaBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
};
```

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't have the replay or stop logic. The 2 ctaBtn functions are just telling the call-to-action button to change when the mouse is over it or not.
Look at the end of the animation timeline, there might be another keyframe with more code on it.

Comment: Thanks Garry,
I've taken the replay button out, the first line stop(); is the stop function on frame 2 to run the Tweens of text and cta button, which just has a roll over state, but how do I then make it return to frame 1 and repeat the loop, whilst play frame 2 for the full length of time need eg 15 secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some new code that will reset the timeline to frame 1 after 15 seconds using a timer. See comments for explanation. Note that 
I've also noticed that your return type 'Void' should be lowercase on the init() function. I've fixed it here as well.

```
stop();

import com.greensock.TweenNano;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

//make timer settings
timer = 0;
durationSecs = 15;

countup = function(){
    timer++;
    trace('rar');
    if(timer>=durationSecs){
        _root.gotoAndPlay(1);
        timer = 0;
        clearInterval( countupInterval );
        trace('clear');
    }
}

countupInterval = setInterval(countup,1000);

init();

function init():Void
{

    TweenNano.to(imgBG,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:0,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt1,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:1,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt2,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:2,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(txt2,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:5,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt3,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:6,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(txt3,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:9,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(txt4,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:10,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(txt4,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:15,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(hpLogoBlue,0,{_alpha:100,delay:0,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

    TweenNano.to(ctaBtn,.5,{_alpha:100,delay:11,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});
    TweenNano.to(ctaBtn,.5,{_alpha:0,delay:15,ease:Quad.easeOut,overwrite:0});

};

ctaBtn.onRollOver = function():Void 
{
    ctaBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
};
ctaBtn.onRollOut = function():Void 
{
    ctaBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
};
```

Comment: Hi Garry, thanks for taking the time to look into this, but I'm afraid its not worked. Perhaps if you have some more time you can look at the actual Flash file which I've just uploaded onto DropBox. Its very frustrating not being able to fix it
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7ex7qlvczfgmp8/300x250_B.zip?dl=0

Comment: what doesn't work? is there an error? Or is it compiling incorrectly?

Comment: Cant be sure what is incorrect but I'm now left with a blank screen, probably stuck on frame 1 or some think. Source file is on DropBox if you'd like a quick look.